# Cmd line arg "^" output "more?"

Tags: c, cmd

The following is a simple code that accepts one command line argument, other than the programs name of course, and checks to see if it is an integer between 1 and 32.

1. cmd prompt: cd c:\somefolder
2. cmd prompt: c:\somefolder> gcc -o myCode myCode.c
3. cmd prompt: c:\somefolder> myCode 5
4. cmd prompt: c:\somefolder> Your arg is accepted.
5. cmd prompt: c:\somefolder> myCode ^
6. cmd prompt: More?

Then it waits for another input. How can I check for this like I checked for letters?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a cmd-line arg between 1 and 32.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        int x;
        char *ptr;
        long y = strtol(argv[1], &ptr , 10);
        int l = strlen(argv[1]);                

        for (x = 0; x <= (l - 1); x++)
        {

            if (argv[1][x] >= 'a' && argv[1][x] <= 'z')
            {
                printf("\nYou can't enter letters.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else if (argv[1][x] >= 'A' && argv[1][x] <= 'Z')
            {
                printf("\nYou can't enter letters.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //printf("\nCeaser shift accepted.\n");
            }
        }

        if (y <= 0 || y > 32)
        {
            printf("\nCeaser shift must be between 1 and 32.\n", y);
            return 0;
        }

    }

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        printf("You entered too many arg.");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("\nYour arg is accepted.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that it is a Caesar cipher/shift.

Comment: To check character classes, you should use the `<ctype.h>` header and macros/functions such as `isalpha()`, `islower()`, `isupper()`, `isdigit()`.

Comment: @Jonathan yes, I am using this to encrypt a message using Caesar cipher. I will also look into <ctype.h> thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is special console sign (Escape Character [1,2]), you can't do anything.

You may run your program like that:

```
myCode "^" # (with double quotes)
```

or

```
myCode ^^
```

[1] http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

[2] http://www.robvanderwoude.com/useless.php#EscapeChar

Comment: Interesting. I hope a user doesn't accidentally enter that as an input for my program.